# Applying chosen image url to hidden form input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to take working javascript that applies an image url to a CSS background property and also put that url into a hidden form input.

The following javascript works like so: The modal pops up and an array of images are shown. When the image link is clicked, the modal is closed and the image is applied to the background of the container. All of this works perfectly. *Note, there is no submit button, this JS is called by clicking an image in the array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#exampleModal .modal-body img').click(function() {
  const src = $(this).attr("src");
  $('.my-container > .middle').css("background-image", `url(${src})`);
  jQuery.noConflict();
  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

});
</script>
```

I can do the insert that I need for the database side, but I"m missing the key component here, and that is the image URL. I need somehow, when the image is clicked and the above javascript is called, to pass the image URL into the input 'page_content' shown in the modal form below. Once that's done I can finish my AJAX call.

Here is the modal with a form that contains a hidden input for the panel type (8) and a hidden input for the content( What I want to be the chosen image URL)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">

        <?php foreach($imageResult as $im): ?>
          <?php if($im['type'] == 'background' ) {?>
        <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>">
      <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </div>

      <form  id="bgForm" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="page_content" id="bgContent" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="panel_type" value="8">
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I simultaneously pass the URL to the hidden form type when applying it to the CSS?

Comment: try $('#bgContent').val(src); in the scripts click function.

Comment: I think that worked, but I'm testing with a console log real quick

Comment: I think I'm printing this incorrectly, would I just do console.log('#bgContent')?

Comment: If you want to log to console then console.log( $('#bgContent').val() )